# How to backup files from production server files before uploading using Ant?

Tags: windows, ant, copy, backup, fileset

I have 3 folders on Windows system:

- S - Source code folder.
- A - Application server folder.
- B - Backup folder.

I am able to copy all modified/new files from S to A by using Ant `copy` command.

My requirement is before copying/overwriting files S to A, I have to take backup of all files from A to B.

I.e. I want to copy those files from A to B which will get updated from S to A

In simple terms taking backup of production system folder before uploading new code.

---

Copying from A to B is not the problem, the problem is to get the list of files by comparing S & A and then copy them from A to B Suppose I have 3 files in on S & A which are in sync `One.txt`, `Two.txt`, `Three.txt`. Now the developer only changed `Three.txt` So I will have to copy `Three.txt` from S to A, but before overriding file on A, I want to take the back of `Three.txt` by copying it from A to B.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You were able to use Ant to copy files from S to A; what happened when you tried doing the same thing for A to B?

Comment: Thanks, Copying from A to B is not the problem, problem is to get the list of files by comparing S & A and then copy them from A to B

Suppose I have 3 files in on S & A which are in sync

One.txt
Two.txt
Three.txt

Now the developer only changed Three.txt

So I will have to copy Three.txt from S to A, but before overriding file on A, I want to take the back of Three.txt by copying it from A to B

Comment: It sounds like Ant's `intersect` resource collection might be what you're looking for: https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html#intersect

Comment: After spending good time i have create the build file, but i am unable to post here in comment box and also i am not able to find link to  answer my own question